# how to go from pixel coordinates to angle off the optical axis (Object detection alignment)

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, computer-vision, robotics

I am making a robot that detects a ball and goes to it.

Because I am doing the detection on a raspberry pi I thought that it will be better to work with images and not with real time detection.

The robot rotates 45 degrees and take a photo. If the ball isn’t detected, it moves another 45 degrees till it detects the ball.

Here it is the problem: after the detection the ball could be anywhere on the image, so I need to make an algorithm that says to the robot how many degrees it should turn to be centered aligned to the ball.

Here is how the robot detects the ball:

- Google cloud vision API, and if the ball isn't detected...
- a TF-lite model detection will run. If the ball isn't detected with this...
- it rotates.

The camera used for the project: Raspberry pi Noir V2 (res HD)

Language: Python, but mostly I need ideas.

P.S.: I am a newbie to robotics, so any help will be appreciated.
Sorry for missing out some info, it is the first time asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: and what is the question/problem? you presented a plan. -- guessing here... if you can find out the horizontal "field of view" (degrees) of your camera, and the horizontal resolution of the picture, and you have the coordinates of the ball in the picture, I can tell you how many degrees to turn, and the required calculations for that.

Comment: I need to make an algorithm that calculate the degrees the robot should turn to be aligned,Angle of View: 62.2 x 48.8 degrees,the resolution of the pic(1920x1080),and i know the x1,x2,y1,y2 of the label box.But i want the formula mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking how to handle a camera matrix, how to work with the "intrinsics" of a camera, and a little linear algebra.

[specs for the "Raspberry pi Noir V2 (res HD)"](https://elinux.org/Rpi_Camera_Module#Technical_Parameters_.28v.2_board.29):

- 1.12 µm pixel size (design)
- 3.04 mm focal length (design)
- full resolution: 3280 x 2464 (design)
- full resolution FoV: H 62.28°, V 48.83°, D 74.16° (calculated)

The camera matrix `K` generally looks like

[image: camera matrix]

The full resolution focal length (in pixels) is `f = (3.04 mm) / (1.12 µm/pixel) = 2714.3 [pixels]`

The "1920x1080" video mode does no binning, only cropping. That means `f = 2714` goes for it too. That means the video mode's field of view is actually 38.96° horizontally, 22.5° vertically, 44.2° diagonally.

NB: for binned modes, if the binning is 2x2, then `f` halves, i.e. use 1357.

I have no information on how still pictures are produced. The full sensor has 4:3 aspect ratio. Assuming a 1920x1080 frame is fully fitted in there (touching sides, cropping top and bottom), the scale factor is 0.585 and f = 1589, with FoV being 62.28° by 37.54°, 69.46° diagonally.

Focal length can also be calculated from resolution and field of view, but pixel pitch and lens focal length are the nominal design parameters and the field of view derives from that (and imperfections like lens distortion).

Then we have `cx = (width-1) / 2 = 959.5` and `cy = (height-1) / 2 = 539.5`.

So now you have the values for the matrix.

A 3D point `p` is projected onto the image by calculating `K p`, which is a matrix multiplication. The opposite can be done. You can reproject a point on the picture back into the world. It's now a vector, a ray, a direction.

If you have `(x,y)` as picture coordinates, calculate:

```
v_x = (x - cx) / f
# v_y = (y - cy) / f
```

and finally the horizontal angle:

```
alpha = atan(v_x) # radians, or
alpha = atan(v_x) * 180/pi # degrees
```

(Diagonal angle away from the optical axis would be `atan(hypot(v_x, v_y))`)

For a point on the left edge (x=0), that would mean turning 19.5 degrees left.

All of this assumes that the picture was not distorted by the lens. For small angles, this doesn't matter. Some cameras have special lenses that hardly distort at all. Some cameras, especially action cameras, intentionally have almost-fisheye lenses (meaning strong distortion).

If you need to deal with lens distortion, that's another topic. There are common models for lens distortion that work with as few as 4 parameters. Both MATLAB and OpenCV come with calibration methods.

Comment: I think I understood the main concept,but some informations are lacking for me ,because i just got in the high school .Can you explain  little simpler or code it for me  to understand.Thank you!

Comment: the constants, `f, cx, cy`, are given as numbers, and the expressions for `v_x` and `alpha` are given too. you can just take these and reproduce the numbers example at the end.

Comment: Ok,but the label box has 2 x (x1,x2) and 2 y(y1,y2),do I need just one of them?Sorry for kepping you explaining to me ,but i have to understand this because if for a class !Thank you again!

Comment: calculate the center of the box then.

Comment: Ok,and one last question,i need to known in which part to rotate,how do i know in which part?

Comment: what's a "part"? what are the choices?

Comment: If i rotate in left and right?

Comment: `alpha`: negative is left, positive is right. work the example (`x=0`) and you'll see the result and then you can compare it to what I wrote there (19.5 degrees left).

Comment: Ok ,got it !On your example :cx=(width-1)/2=695.5 ,which is 1940 ,shouldn’t be supposed to be 1920?

Comment: ah right, typo. width = 1920, so cx = 959.5, not 969.5

Comment: okey,just got a problem:)How do you got 19.5 degrees left in the example?
My calculations:
cx = 969.5
v_x = (0-969.5)/f(1589) = -0.61
atan(-0.61)*180/3.14 = -31.40 rad

Comment: mind which value for the focal length you use. 1589 was a guess. I have no idea how that camera makes pictures. my example assumes the video mode, with f=2714 (and cx = 959.5, not 969.5)